# Append changes to existing text showing wrong name

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, list, custom-list, modified

I have a custom list on SP Online 2013 with the following customizations:

- Create a version each time you edit an item in this list? - **Yes**
- A new column added (multi-line) with Append Changes to Existing Text? - **Yes**
- Allow management of content types - **Yes**
- Launch form in Dialog - **Yes**

There are no workflows or anything else.

Whoever is the creator of an item in the list shows up as the modified by no matter what. I've tried this with several users of different access levels.

Any thoughts on what I could try?

Comment: Does the same happen for admin level access accounts? Try with 2 different admin accounts

Comment: @RansherSingh Tried it with accounts that have site collection admin privileges. Still got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the PowerShell below to get the field schema (Run SharePoint Online Management Shell as administrator):

```
$SiteURL = "https://domain.sharepoint.com"

 Write-Host "Loading CSOM libraries" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow

 Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

Write-Host "Lib. successfully loaded !" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Green 

$scriptPath = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

$User = Read-Host -Prompt "username"

$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString

Write-Host "Trying to reach $SiteURL // Handling ClientContext..." -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow  

$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL) 

$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User, $password) 

$Context.Credentials = $credentials 

$context.RequestTimeOut = 5000 * 60 * 10;

$web = $context.Web

$site = $context.Site 

$context.Load($web)

$context.Load($site)

try

{

 $context.ExecuteQuery()
 Write-Host "Connected !" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Green
}
 catch
 {
  Write-Host "Impossible to reach $SiteURL : bad password ?" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Red
  return
 }
 $list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle("Custom List");

 $fields = $list.Fields;

 $context.Load($web)

 $context.Load($site)

 $context.Load($list)

 $context.Load($fields)

 $context.ExecuteQuery()

 $fields | select SchemaXML  |  Export-Csv -path "d:\schema.csv";`
```

Then follow the article [Modified By Column does not get updated](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/victorbutuza/2015/08/04/modified-by-column-does-not-get-updated/) check the out of the box Editor field SchemaXML.